# Understanding the Youtube Data API Quota limitations

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I was wondering if I could get some help understanding the Youtube Data Api, specifically Google's website says: "Each project starts with 10,000 units per day, an amount sufficient for the overwhelming majority of our API users."

Is this 10,000 per person who signs in through your project then? Because 10,000 does not in any way seem sufficient! A youtube Search alone takes 100 units if I understand the documentation, so 5 people each doing 20 searches and your project is done for the day. This seems to make building a robust Youtube browser all but impossible for a user base bigger than 2.

As you can tell I'm a bit frustrated and sure I must be missing something. Any clarifications you can offer would be appreciated.

Comment: Yea I have a workaround: just upload manually. Seriously, why would I use API and write an application to upload only 6, 7 videos a day.

Answer (score 3):

If you check the following screen

[image]

only one of the quotas says "per user" the others are project based quotas.

You have a quota of 10000 per day for the total project.

[Quota cost](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) is calculated by the request resource.

A youtube Search alone takes 100 units per request. if I understand the documentation, so 5 people each doing 20 searches and your project is done for the day.

10000 (limit) / 100 (quota cost) = 100 search requests pre day.

It sounds to me like you have understood the quota system perfectly.  If you intend to make more requests than that you will need to request additional quota.

Comment: How can Google think this is remotely even close to enough/ Where's their logic?

Comment: This is a free api you are not paying to use it.   Do you need more logic than that?

Comment: but what does "queries per minute" mean?

Comment: This is the quota cost allotted your application can send on behalf of a single user per minute.    While you can request an extension of the project total you can not request extension of the user quotas. So even if you have a million project quota a single user can never go above the quota usage per minute